# Error : expecting ] token after element when using ajax.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I keep getting an error when i run the debugger that says "SyntaxError: missing ] after element list"

the first request always works as intended but all of the follow requests return a syntax error. can someone explain to me what i'm messing up here. please and thankyou.

```
$("#submitmsg").click(function(){
    alert('start');      
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();  
    $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});                
    $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");  
    return false;  
}); 
setInterval($.ajax({
        url : 'http:www.whatever.com/log.html',
        type : 'GET', 
            success : function(data)
            {
                document.getElementById('chatframe').innerHTML = data; 
            }
        }), 500);  

</script>
```

Comment: The URL is wrong, and doing an ajax call two times every second doesn't really seem like a very good idea ?

Comment: Oh, and the entire interval is wrong, there is no function call and it's not properly closed.

Comment: And not enough jQuery.  You will anger the gods. Replace `document.getElementById('chatframe').innerHTML = data;` with `$('#chatframe').html(data);`

Comment: and `.attr("value"...` should be `.val("")`

Answer (score 0):

your setInterval is wrong, it should be, `setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);` like

```
setInterval(ajax_func, 500);

function ajax_func() {
  $.ajax({
        url : 'http://www.whatever.com/log.html',
        type : 'GET', 
        success : function(data) {
            document.getElementById('chatframe').innerHTML = data; 
        }
  });
}
```